# How to see what conditional formatting is used for a cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I was given an Excel. Some cells are conditionally formatted. However, I was not told of the exact rule used for such conditional formatting. Is there a way to find out the rule, please? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CFConditions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to do this manually, then click the CF icon from the Home tab, and select Manage Rules

[image]